# How do I calculate the radius of a turtle circle object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to implement collisions between turtle objects that are circles. But for this, I need the radii of the circles.

```py
import turtle as t

screen=t.Screen()
screen.setup(1.0,1.0)
screen.bgcolor("#000")
worldsize=100
screen.setworldcoordinates(-worldsize, -worldsize, worldsize, worldsize)

obj=t.Turtle("circle")
size=5
obj.shapesize(size, size)
obj.goto(50,50)

width=screen.window_width()
height=screen.window_height()
```

Doing some research, I discovered that one turtle unit is 20 pixels and so I can start by converting from turtle units to pixels by simply doing `size * 20`. But this, of course, is not enough since the world coordinates are being modified. So, correspondingly, I could multiply by the ratio between the window size and the world size.

But this would give me 2 radii:

```py
rx=10 * size * worldsize/width
ry=10 * size * worldsize/height
```

So, now I have 2 radii, which defeats the purpose of a radius since the radius is meant to be constant all around the circle.

Comment: If you change the coordinates in an anisotropic way, the turtle shape turns to an ellipse.

Comment: You don't need to do all this conversion to pixels and window-space, just do your collision checking in the native space used by the library.

Comment: @tkausl I want to control the world coordinates because it affects calculations made  in a simulation im making with these collisions

Comment: @YvesDaoust How can I prevent this?

Comment: Your window size or the view into this virtual world should in no way affect calculations made inside that virtual coordinate system. If it does, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @tkausl It's a bit like zoom, when the world coordinates have a large range like -1000 to 1000 and objects are moving at 10 units/s then they'll appear to be moving much slower compared to if the world coordinates ranged from -100 to 100. They don't necessarily affect the calculations directly, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @tkausl: if I am right, the turtle keeps a fixed size and is circular on the display. So in the native space, it turns to an ellipse.

Comment: Stick to an isotropic change of coordinates.

Comment: May you provide an example as to how? And subsequently how one could get the radius?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my exaggerated attempt to illustrate the OP's issue.  Let's draw three circles of the same size, one using `circle()`, one use `dot()` and one being the mouse cursor itself:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WORLD_SIZE = 100
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

diameter = 10

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1.0, 0.5)  # exaggerate the aspect ratio when we do setworldcoordinates

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

# screen.setworldcoordinates(-WORLD_SIZE, -WORLD_SIZE, WORLD_SIZE, WORLD_SIZE)

turtle = Turtle('circle')
turtle.shapesize(diameter / CURSOR_SIZE)
# turtle.shapesize(diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * height/WORLD_SIZE/2, diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)

turtle.circle(diameter/2)  # circle uses a radius

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(18, 18)

turtle.dot(diameter)
# turtle.dot(diameter * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)  # dot() will never not be a circle

turtle.goto(36, 36)

print(turtle.distance(0, 0))  # if you change WORLD_SIZE, these are always the same
print(turtle.distance(50, 0))  # as they are measured from the cursor hot spot
print(turtle.distance(0, 50))

screen.exitonclick()
```

This gives us what we expect:

[image]

Now uncomment the line:

```
# screen.setworldcoordinates(-WORLD_SIZE, -WORLD_SIZE, WORLD_SIZE, WORLD_SIZE)
```

and we get:

[image]

Now uncomment these two lines:

```
# turtle.shapesize(diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * height/WORLD_SIZE/2, diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)
...
# turtle.dot(diameter * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)  # dot() will never not be a circle
```

And we now get:

[image]

Now, following up on the comments:

> Stick to an isotropic change of coordinates. – Yves Daoust
>
> May you provide an example as to how? – yungmaz13

The issue being that `setworldcoordinates()` affects drawing but has no effect on cursor images nor operators like `dot()`.

Let's rework our code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WORLD_SIZE = 100
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

diameter = 10

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1.0, 1.0)

width, height = screen.window_width(), screen.window_height()

world_size_height = WORLD_SIZE * height / width  # assumption, screen width > screen height

screen.setworldcoordinates(-WORLD_SIZE, -world_size_height, WORLD_SIZE, world_size_height)

turtle = Turtle('circle')
turtle.shapesize(diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * height/world_size_height/2, diameter/CURSOR_SIZE * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)

turtle.circle(diameter/2)  # circle uses a radius

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(18, 18)

turtle.dot(diameter * width/WORLD_SIZE/2)  # dot() will never not be a circle

turtle.goto(36, 36)

print(turtle.distance(0, 0))  # if you change WORLD_SIZE, these are always the same
print(turtle.distance(50, 0))  # as they are measured from the cursor hot spot
print(turtle.distance(0, 50))

screen.exitonclick()
```

And we end up with:

[image]

Does this give you insight into the problem and some idea how to fix it?

Comment: Yes! Wonderfully explained

Comment: Question though: What is the purpose of `CURSOR_SIZE`? I see that it reduces the shapesize but why is it called cursor size? What does cursor size mean?

Comment: The turtle function `shapesize()` uses *relative* values, e.g. "twice the current size."  If instead we want to work in *absolute* values like pixels, we need to know what the default cursor size is in the first place.  `CURSOR_SIZE` is a rough estimate of such.